# JavaScript onTouch not working

Tags: javascript, touch

Can anybody tell me why this onTouch handler isn't firing.

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById('existingContent');
var myButton = '<a href="#" onClick="logOut();" ontouch="logOut()">log out</a>';
myDiv.appendChild(myButton);

function logOut() {
  alert('hello');
}
```

I am using iPad 1.

Comment: I am using iPad 1. logout() could be anything, the ontouch event won't fire at all. I'm watching firebug to ensure no errors. In my code I'm just calling alert to see if the event is successfully fired at all.

Comment: The onclick handler works fine in firefox. The only issue I'm having is getting the ontouch to fire in iPad.

Comment: T.J. - you're right. This isn't my real world code. I've stripped out the fluff to get down to it. My code is namespaces in a self executing anonymous function and there is a lot more text in the string. But, that doesn't explain why my onclick fires in a desktop browser on not on my iPad.

Comment: Its a miracle that this code actually works. Since when does `Node.appendChild` take a string?

Comment: @Keith: Strongly recommend creating an actual, complete, stripped-down example. The above is basically pseudo-code. Show something that, when pasted into a live environment like http://jsbin.com, would actually demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My recommendation would be the same as the one proposed [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Touch_events) on MDN:

```
var el = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas");  
el.addEventListener("touchstart", handleStart, false);
```

My hesitation with the ontouch attribute is cross-device support. For this you might consider feature detection.

[Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) is a popular way to determine if touch is enabled at runtime.

If the events above are enabled, the classes touch or no-touch would be added to the html element and used to determine if the code above should run.

EDIT:

In subsequent days I ran across [this](http://www.queness.com/post/11755/11-multi-touch-and-touch-events-javascript-libraries) document describing Touch Events. As with much of technology, there is still more to it...

Comment: Using .addEventListener() and the touchstart event did the trick. Thanks for helping a noob without making me feel dumb.

Comment: Thank you sir. With technology growing at such a rapid pace, increasingly, we-are-all-noobs. All the best!

Comment: after many months of banging my head against the wall trying to get event listeners to work cross-browser; I've discovered that assigning with el.onclick = myFunction(); is really the only reliable solution.  There are drawbacks for not using the .addEventListener() method, but until all the browsers get on the same page, I'm willing to work around the limitations of .onclick =

Comment: Seeing el. makes me think of Backbone.js. Other frameworks handle events well too... jQuery, Sencha, etc. It is good to not have to reinvent the wheel sometimes. Also git hub is important. Best! Nash

Answer (score 5):

There is no `"touch"` event at all. You can find `touchstart`, `touchend`, `touchmove` and `touchcancel` events, as is shown in [this link](http://www.w3.org/TR/touch-events/#dfn-touchcancel). I think you must use `touchstart` in your HTML:

```
ontouchstart="logOut()"
```

Also see this [webpage](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html).

Answer (score -1):

Try using **onfocus="logOut()"** instead of ontouch="logOut()"