# Javascript method does not get call on a click of a button from my mobile application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I have a simple page in HTML that calls a JavaScript method on click of a button. This works fine when i call it from my computer. However when i try to run this from my mobile application (Note: i am building a mobile app using HMTL5 CSS and Javascript, cordova) when i click on the Submit button it would just not do anything not even print the alert statement. i am stumped and have no idea why is it behaving different ?

```
<div data-role="page" id="PostUserUpdates" >
  <div data-role="header"  data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
  </div>
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <pre><B>
                     <div id="resultDayOfWeek"></div>
                     <div id="resultNum"></div>
                     <div id="resultDir"></div>
                     <div id="resultStop"></div>
                     <div id="resultTime"></div>     
                     </B> 
                     </pre>
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
      <legend>Choose Status</legend>
      <label for="Arrived/Left">Arrived/Left</label>
      <input type="radio" name="status" id="Arrived/Left" value="Arrived/Left">
      <label for="Delayed">Delayed</label>
      <input type="radio" name="status" id="Delayed" value="Delayed">   
      <label for="Canceled">Canceled</label>
      <input type="radio" name="status" id="Canceled" value="Canceled">
      <label for="getupdate">getupdate from others</label>
      <input type="radio" name="status" id="getupdate" value="getupdate">
      <label for="Other">Other</label>
      <input type="radio" name="status" id="Other" value="Other">
    </fieldset>
    <textarea name="addinfo" id="info"> Comments goes here.... </textarea>
    <button class="ui-btn ui-btn-b"  onclick="postSubmit();" >Submit </button>
    <div id="poststatus"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

.

```
function postSubmit()
{
alert("In PostSubmit");
var dow=  document.getElementById("resultDayOfWeek").innerHTML;
var busnum= document.getElementById("resultNum").innerHTML;
var direction= document.getElementById("resultDir").innerHTML;
var stopname=  document.getElementById("resultStop").innerHTML;
var time= document.getElementById("resultTime").innerHTML; 
var value ="" ;
if (document.getElementById('Arrived/Left').checked) {
value = document.getElementById('Arrived/Left').value;
}
else if (document.getElementById('Delayed').checked) {
value = document.getElementById('Delayed').value;
}
else if (document.getElementById('Canceled').checked) {
value = document.getElementById('Canceled').value;
}
else if (document.getElementById('getupdate').checked) {
value = document.getElementById('getupdate').value;
}
else{
value = document.getElementById('Other').value;
}
alert(value);
alert(dow);
alert(busnum); 
alert(direction);
alert(stopname);
alert(time);
var comments = document.getElementById('info').value;
alert(comments);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cause firering not click event, but touch event ( touchstart, touchend, touchmove and touchcancel )

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10956637/javascript-ontouch-not-working) to get example

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:
Try putting the javascript part in **head**.
Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PRNVy/).

Solution 2: Simply use jQuery .click. (put it in `$(document).ready()`)

```
$("#myButton").click(postSubmit);
```